# how to display excel data in tabular form?

Tags: android

I want to display my excel sheet data in tabular form in android .for which i have successfully displayed the excel data in my output but not in tabular form .

Answer (score 0):

How about using server of python? 
You can parse data by tabula and get data in Android from the server.

For example,

```
import numpy as np
import tabula
import csv
import re

PDF_FILE_NAME = "ORIGINAL3.pdf" 
CSV_FILE_NAME = "output.csv"

# Read pdf into DataFrame

df = tabula.read_pdf(PDF_FILE_NAME)
df = df.replace(np.nan, '', regex=True)
print(df)
print(df.shape)
tabula.convert_into(PDF_FILE_NAME, "output.csv", output_format="csv")

with open(CSV_FILE_NAME, 'r') as csvFile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvFile)
    for row in reader:
        row = [x for x in row if x != '']
        row = [x.split() for x in row]
        flatten = [item for sublist in row for item in sublist]

        pattern = '\d\d\.'
        if not re.match(pattern, flatten[0]):
            continue

        print(flatten)
        print('\n')
```

If you to get stuck into using tabula with Java, 
it's good way to just change the way to solve it like my suggestion, I think.

Answer (score 0):

You can read a CSV file in Android and then wrap each value with the HTML `<td>` and `</td>` and then add the necessary HTML for a table and display in a `webview` component.

This is how I display CSV data in a tabular format in Android.

e.g. something like (this is not tested and is a mashup of the code I use)

```java
// Do file opening stuff

StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

BufferedReader reader;
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fileInputStream));
     while( (line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
       stringBuilder.append("<tr>\n");
       String[] RowData = line.split(",");
       for( String cell : RowData) {
          stringBuilder.append("<td>").append(cell).append("</td>\n");
       }

       stringBuilder.append("</tr>\n");

   }

   String htmlHeader = "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html><meta charset=\"UTF-8\"><body><table>";
   String htmlFooter = "</table></body></html>";

   String finalHTML = htmlHeader + stringBuilder.toString() + htmlFooter;

   webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.WebView);
   webView.loadData(finalHTML, "text/html; charset=utf-8", "UTF-8");
```